Sometimes Magento 2 observers not getting executed after order place event
We recently came across an issue that sometimes all observers related to Magento 2 order created after event not getting executed.
We didn't found any similarities between such orders. This is very rare and found nothing that could trigger such issue.
We tried looking into the Logs but found none for such orders and during that time. We have also not found a way to replicate the issue and it is only replicating on live server.
However, we tried to find out the issue manually but it seems really complicated as there are hundreds of observer that we can't go though each file. The issue could be with the plugins or the code specific related to product so it becomes very difficult for us to find out the real cause.
Please provide me a solution by which I can quickly identify such issue?
I shall be very thankful to you.

it will be more helpful if you put your code also here, your event.xml and your observer file
